# Xamppp: SQL Insert stops working when I add Foreign Keys to the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, foreign-keys

**Attendance Table**:

1. AttendID (AUTO_INCREMENT) (Primary Key)
2. StudID
3. ClassID
4. attended

This SQL Insert is inserting records to my **Attendance Table**:

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into attend (StudID, ClassID, attended) values ('$data', '$data1', 1)", $connection);
```

But When I make the [StudID] and [ClassID] columns as *Foreign Keys* each one to a different table, The Insert won't insert records to my **Attendance Table** and there is no error showing in my code.

Help Please :(

Comment: do you know for sure that there is a record in the student and class tables that corresponds with your foreign keys?

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.